# Changing values in a pandas dataframe multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a list of dataframes, each has a multi-index. one column is a varName, the other is 'round'.

The values in the varName column are numbers. I have another dataframe that is a mapping of the numbers to labels. I want to use map() on the varName column, but since it's part of the index, there IS no varName column.

I've tried to copy the varname column, or make it not part of the index anymore, but none of these things seem to work.

Comment: [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Actually, the correct answer for this specific case turned out to be "do the mapping on the data before that column becomes the index." Which won't work in all cases, but works for this one...

Answer (score 1):

If `varName` is the `name` of one of the `MultiIndex` levels, you should be able to:

```
df.reset_index(level='varName')
```

to convert `varName` to a `column` and then use `map()`. If `varName` is not the `name`, you should still be able to use `level=0` (or `1`).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do something like:

```
df.reset_index(level=1).merge(df2)
```

this is assuming level=1 is your common column (eg 'varName') between two dfs. if you wish you can than set_index for the label name, like:

```
df.reset_index(level=1).merge(df2).set_index(['labels'],append=True)
```